# Error bars are not plotted when axes are reversed (plotCI from package plotrix)

Tags: r, plot, axes, plotrix

I want to change the point of origin for a plot with vertical and horizontal error bars. I'm using the plotCI function from the 'plotrix' package for plotting.

A very short reproducible example:

```
x <- c(1, 2)
y <- c(3, 4)
err.x <- c(0.5, 0.2)
err.y <- c(0.25, 0.3)
plotCI(x, y, uiw = err.x, err = "x",
       ylim = range(y+err.y, y-err.y))
plotCI(x, y, uiw = err.y, err = "y", add = T)
```

Everything is fine in this plot. I got both horizontal and vertical error bars.

```
plotCI(x, y, uiw = err.x, err = "x",
       ylim = rev(range(y+err.y, y-err.y)))
plotCI(x, y, uiw = err.y, err = "y", add = T)
```

Here, I only get the horizontal error bars. It seems as if the reversal of the y-axis wasn't 'recognized' by the second call to plotCI.

Any ideas?!? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love `plotrix` and its associated functions but I think what you're trying to do is hampered by the `arrows()` function that `plotCI()` relies on not honoring the `ylim` reversal.  You can instead use `ggplot2` to get the plot you want:

```
x <- c(1, 2)
y <- c(3, 4)
err.x <- c(0.5, 0.2)
err.y <- c(0.25, 0.3)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x,y,err.x,err.y), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-err.y, ymax=y+err.y), width=0.05) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=x-err.x, xmax=x+err.x), height=0.05) + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Forrest, thanks a lot for your answer. I guess I won't use plotrix after all in this case. Your solution really seems more flexible.